# no module named urllib3 - trying to install pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip, redhat

I'm trying to install python 2.7 and pip onto my system. I'm working on redhat linux. Previously I had been following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4

which seemed to work for installing python, however while trying to install pip I get the following message: 
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.

ImportError: No module named urllib3

this is after using `curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"`

and then using `python get-pip.py`

I've tried a couple installations of python 2.7.2 and 2.7.9, both have the same problem.

I do not have root privileges on this machine. When I ran the configuration file while setting up my python I tried to use --with-ensurepip but obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the tar file of python 2.7 and build it from [source](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2713/).

Followed by steps [mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191390/how-to-use-sudo-command-to-install-tar-gz) for installation.

As far as pip is concerned, you can download the tar file from [here](https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files) and follow the [same steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191390/how-to-use-sudo-command-to-install-tar-gz)